# Javascript para que el usuario seleccione su direccion

Tags: javascript, ajax

me gustaría saber cual sería el código para que un usuario escribiese su dirección, con un preview dela dirección que está escribiendo, gracias por vuestro tiempo, lo siento si es muy básico, soy bastante nuevo en esto

Comment: ***El código será aquel que tú mismo escribas***. Te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones, lo que ocasionará su cierre. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta añadiendo el código de lo que has intentado, explicando los errores o dificultades y el resultado deseado, entonces has clic en [edit]. Puedes además leer cómo elaborar un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Además, lectura recomendada: [¿por qué hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hola buenas!

Para hacer algun tipo de autocompletado de una direccion tendrias que usar alguna `API` para ello. He estado buscando y puede que lo que mas te interese sea esto
**https://smartystreets.com/articles/autocomplete** para autocompletar un input

#### Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias tio, ahora me lo leeré, pero por el video que he visto, es eso 100%